# How to pull data from JSON structure (document) in Mongo DB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, codeigniter

I am using Mongo DB and I have the following document:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5673f753dbafbed2f4b12afc"),
        "user_id" : "5",
        "user_name" : "Aditya",
        "thought" : [
                {
                        "thought_id" : "4",
                        "thought_text" : "aditya here",
                        "th_inserted_at" : "2015-12-17 11:50:35",
                        "comments" : [
                                {
                                        "cmt_from_id" : "4",
                                        "comment_txt" : "stop bala",
                                        "cmt_inserted_at" : "2015-12-17 12:50:35
"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "followings" : [
                {
                        "following_id" : "4"
                },
                {
                        "following_id" : "1"
                }
        ],
        "followers" : [
                {
                        "follower_id" : "4"
                },
                {
                        "follower_id" : "2"
                },
                {
                        "follower_id" : "1"
                }
        ],
        "role" : "user",
        "profile_pic" : "somepic",
        "review" : [
                {
                        "review_id" : "2",
                        "review_txt" : "nice play",
                        "play_id" : "1",
                        "rev_inserted_at" : "2015-12-17 18:50:35"
                }
        ]
}
```

How do I get the nested document using Codeigniter mongo DB's where clause. For instance, I want to fetch all data within the thoughts section where thought_id =4. 
I am using [this library](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Using-MongoDB-in-Codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
// Query MongoDB: Active document library usage example
$info = $this->mongo_db->where('thought_id', '4')->get('collection_name_here');  

// Query MongoDB: Command usage example
$info= $this->mongo_db->command(array(
    'geoNear'    => 'buildings', 
    'near'       => array(53.228482, -0.547847), 
    'num'        => 10, 
    'nearSphere' => TRUE,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fired the following query in the Mongo DB terminal:

```
  db.wall.find({},
   {thought: { $elemMatch: { thought_id: "4" }} })
```

And I get the following result as expected:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5673f753dbafbed2f4b12afc"), 
    "thought" : [
        {
            "thought_id" : "4", 
            "thought_text" : "aditya here", 
            "th_inserted_at" : "2015-12-17 11:50:35", 
            "comments" : [
                {
                    "cmt_from_id" : "4", 
                    "comment_txt" : "stop bala", 
                    "cmt_inserted_at" : "2015-12-17 12:50:35"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now how do I represent the above mentioned query in Codeigniter syntax using this  [library](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Using-MongoDB-in-Codeigniter)  ???